# spring-integration 5.x with mixed mode (servlet http inbound and reactive webclient outbound)

Tags: spring, spring-integration, dsl, reactive

I'm having to re-use an internal framework that requires spring-mvc (servlet) inbound gateways but makes downstream HTTP calls using reactive `webclient`.

Our current implementation using a `gateway()` call to a `Transformer` to make and retrieve the `webclient` call.

```
@Component
public class WebClientCall1 extends GenericTransformer<Message<OurClass>, Message<OurClass>> {

    public Message<OurClass> transform(Message<OurClass> source) {
        WebClient.create("...url...")
                 . ....
                 .retrieve()
                 .toEntity(OurClass.class)
                 .block();
    } 
}
```

We are calling this from an `IntegrationFlow` using the `transform()` method.

I'm wondering if there is a way to avoid using the `block()` method for awaiting and consuming the response, or even if this is a useful idea.

Thanks for any insights or pointers for this.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear why would one treat an  HTTP call as a transformation step, but you probably fully don't need to use a `WebClient` manually, since there is a dedicated `spring-integation-webflux` module: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/webflux.html#webflux.

Its Java DSL provides for us a `WebFlux.outboundGateway()` API to be used in the `.handle()` operator of the `IntegrationFlow`.

Yes, you don't need to call that `.block()`. Only what you need for `IntegatioFlow` is to use `.channel(c -> c.flux())` as an output of that `.handle(WebFlux.outboundGateway())`.

Comment: I will take a look at that.

I'm having to invoke a framework "decorator" for webclient that I'm not sure how to inject into the outbound gateway in that fashion, hence my usage of ```transform()```.

Comment: There is an overloaded factory: `outboundGateway(URI uri, @Nullable WebClient webClient)`